# When were third person pronouns added to Italian?

Tags: pronouns, history

[Proto-Indo-European_language#Pronoun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proto-Indo-European_language#Pronoun):

> PIE had personal pronouns in the first and second grammatical person,
>   but not the third person, where demonstrative pronouns were used
>   instead

[Personal_pronoun#Person_and_number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personal_pronoun#Person_and_number):

> Some languages do not have third-person personal pronouns, instead
>   using demonstratives (e.g. Macedonian) or full noun phrases. Latin
>   used demonstratives rather than third-person pronouns (in fact the
>   third-person pronouns in the Romance languages are descended from the
>   Latin demonstratives).

When were third person pronouns added to Italian?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Latin did not have specific forms for the singular and plural third person pronouns and used the demonstratives in their place: is, ille, ipse, etc. Third-person Italian forms represent the continuation of these forms.

[Pronomi personali](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/pronomi-personali_(Enciclopedia-dell%27Italiano)/):

> Il latino non aveva forme specifiche per i pronomi di terza persona singolare e plurale e usava al loro posto i dimostrativi: is, ille, ipse, ecc. ***Le forme italiane di terza persona rappresentano la continuazione di tali forme.***  In fiorentino antico il numero delle forme di pronomi soggetto di terza persona era ancora maggiore di quello attuale. Era presente, ad es., un pronome plurale maschile elli:
>
> - (1) Ben m’accors’io ch’elli era d’alte lode (Dante, Par. XIV, 124)
>
> C’erano poi le forme ei (con la variante apocopata e’, identica a una delle forme dell’articolo determinativo maschile plurale), per la terza persona singolare e plurale maschile, la e le per la terza persona singolare e plurale femminile, rispettivamente:
>
> - (2) E’ mi par d’or in hora udire il messo (Petrarca, Canz. CCCXLIX, 1)

Treccani.it